# My delete function does not delete the targeted file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically I could upload files based on a project. Whenever I create a project, a new directory is created with the directory name as the project_name e.g. this is a test -> this-is-a-test. But my problem is I couldn't delete a file in a directory.

```
function delete_image($id)
{
    $this->load->model(array('work_model', 'project_model'));
    $result = $this->work_model->get_work($id);
    $result = $this->project_model->get_project($result->project_id);
    $dir = str_replace(" ", "-", $result->project_name);
    $result = $this->work_model->delete($id);
    if (isset($result)){
        unlink('./uploads/' . $dir . '/' . $result->full_path);  
    }
    redirect('admin/project/view_project/' . $result->project_id);
}
```

Need help on this thanks.

Comment: Define "I couldn't". More detailed explanation will help you

Comment: Well the whole delete_image() doesn't work. I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error message where I call the get_project() function and str_replace().

Comment: well,I have to say you have used too many '$result' in your code:)

Comment: Well, I'm designer trying to code. So I was hoping someone could politely answer my question without the sarcasm. Looks like I asked the wrong question at the wrong place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message is self-explanatory.
$result is not an object.

Your problem is matter of debugging, not SO question. And matter of reading error messages, of course. Why do you ask here what's going wrong if you already have explanation from your PHP? And, on the other hand, noone here know your code and have no idea what type of variable get_work($id) supposed to return.

Comment: get_work($id) returns a database result. I'm not really a programmer so I don't get these trivial error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This line is brilliant:

```
if (isset($result)){
```

Of course it is set, you have set it 3 times!

Use different variable names for each result you return. Why not use:

```
function delete_image($id)
{
$this->load->model(array('work_model', 'project_model'));
$work = $this->work_model->get_work($id);
$project = $this->project_model->get_project($work->project_id);
$dir = str_replace(" ", "-", $project->project_name);

if ($this->work_model->delete($id))
{
    unlink('./uploads/' . $dir . '/' . $project->full_path);  
}
redirect('admin/project/view_project/' . $project->project_id);
}
```

If that doesn't work, try some debug steps.

```
var_dump($this->work_model->delete($id));
```

That will tell you TRUE/FALSE, I'd assume right now it is FALSE which is why unlink isn't erroring or succeeding.

Debug is the way forward. We can't do it for you!